# Getting property value from an object parse HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am using angular. I am trying to get the value of a property. 
This is the HTML code

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in propertyCtrl.players">
   <td>{{player.name}}</td>
   <td>{{player.money}}</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="selectedPlayer" value="{{player}}" required="" ng-model="propertyCtrl.player"></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, I'm passing the player's object to the controller

```
propertyCtrl.buy = function(valid) {

    if (valid) {

      var playerObj = propertyCtrl.player;
      var playerMoney =  playerObj.money;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following without success:

```
var playerMoney =  playerObj[money];

var playerMoney =  playerObj['money'];
```

All tries I just get "undefined"

Any help is really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in propertyCtrl.players track by $index">
   <td>{{player.name}}</td>
   <td>{{player.money}}</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="selectedPlayer" value="{{$index}}" 
            required="" 
            ng-model="propertyCtrl.playerIndex">
   </td>
</tr>

var playerObj = propertyCtrl.players[Number(propertyCtrl.playerIndex)];
```

I assume that `players` is an array.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I am using mongodb to store the data, if I use track by index it won't work. Thank you

Comment: @KenethSmith Ok, so maybe player itself has `id`-like column? If yes, instead of using `$index` use `player.id` or something. But - players is `object` or it is `array`? I think, if it is array it does not matter what you have on backend.

Comment: The id is generated by the database. I need to get that so I can get the  object that user is selecting from the radio button. I am getting the object without any issue. It looks like this: playerObj = "{"_id":"58fc4cc042108b09beb24f94","name":"john","id":"001","alias":"Kokkun","money":"1500","photo":"https://res.cloudinary.c ..... }. I need to get the money value.

Comment: So use `track.by player._id` where model in radio is `propertyCtrl.playerId` and value is `{{player._id}}` then use `var playerObj = propertyCtrl.players[propertyCtrl.playerId];`

Comment: playerObj getting undefined after following the steps. It's getting the object by the "propertyCtrl.playerId". But once is added to the rest of the value it gets undefined

Comment: Ok, so what is `players`? Definitely is not an array, it could be an object. So try the following: `for (var key in propertyCtrl.players) { if (propertyCtrl.players.hasOwnProperty(key)) { var tempPlayer = propertyCtrl.players[key]; if (tempPlayer._id === propertyCtrl.id) {playerObj = tempPlayer; }  } }`. Of course you can get syntax errors, cause in inline code it's easy to forget some `{` or `}`

Comment: I do not how to define if players is an array or not. I do not how to call it since it is stored in the back end. I have this function in order to call that "collection?": administradorService.getPlayers()
          .success(function(data){
            propertyCtrl.players = data;

          });  . I followed your code and now I am able to get the money value!! Many thanks. I have never used  hasOwnProperty(key) that's kind of confusing but I will look into that. Thank you

Comment: When you have this `success(function(data){ propertyCtrl.players = data; })`, try to alert it: `success(function(data){ alert(typeof data); alert(JSON.stringify(data)); propertyCtrl.players = data; })`

Comment: @KenethSmith You accepted answer, `for (var key...)...` worked?

Comment: Yes, thank you!. Look at the comment that I posted prior to this one